# What is the equivalence of CreateMutex with name in pthread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, winapi, pthreads, cross-platform

In win32, I write:

```
void Init()
{
    wchar_t szLockName[] = L"processName";
    HANDLE hInitLock = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, szLockName);
    int nRetCode = WaitForSingleObject(hInitLock, INFINITE);
    if(nRetCode == WAIT_OBJECT_0 || nRetCode == WAIT_ABANDONED)
    {
    ...
    }
    ...
    ReleaseMutex(hInitLock);
    CloseHandle(hInitLock);
}
```

if I use pthread in UNIX, how can I create a named mutex?

```
void Init()
{
    char szLockName[] = "processName";
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_mutex_init (&mutex, NULL); //question 1: What init param should I passed in to Obtain or create a mutex with a name like Win32?

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); //question 2: How Can I Obtain the result(WAIT_OBJECT_0, WAIT_ABANDONED) like Win32?
/*
    if(nRetCode == WAIT_OBJECT_0 || nRetCode == WAIT_ABANDONED)
    {
    ...
    }
    ...
*/
    //ReleaseMutex(hInitLock);
    //CloseHandle(hInitLock); //question 3: Does pthread_mutex_unlock  work like (ReleaseMutex & CloseHandle)?
}
```

question 1: What init param should I passed in to Obtain or create a mutex with a name like Win32?
question 2: How Can I Obtain the result(WAIT_OBJECT_0, WAIT_ABANDONED) like Win32?
question 3: Does pthread_mutex_unlock  work like (ReleaseMutex & CloseHandle)?

Comment: There isn't. The closest is a POSIX semaphore. It's best to avoid POSIX if at all possible, particularly anything in `pthreads`. It is the result of abstracting systems that weren't designed with multithreading in mind.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: FYI, if `WaitForSingleObject()` returns `WAIT_ABANDONED`, it means another thread locked the mutex and then terminated without unlocking it. As such, you usually can't make any assumptions about the state of the data that the mutex was protecting. See [Understanding the consequences of WAIT_ABANDONED](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050912-14/?p=34253)